# SSL redirection on registration page, non SSL on others pages

Tags: http, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, https

I have a little problem, here it is :

I woudl like to redirect ALL MY PAGES to http (https to http redirection).
I would like only one page (register.php) to get redirected from http to https.

The main problem, is that when I redirect everything execept register.php on my forum, the https is not valid ! (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvVI4.jpg) since all the ressources like my images (logo for example) are redirected to normal http (so on my https page it can't get the valid https because my images and ressources are not encoded because of the redirection the redirect everything to http).

Here is the code :

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/register\.php$
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/logo.png
RewriteRule (.*) http://mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Best regards to all.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong. You don't want to redirect the registration page at all, you want it to POST *directly* to HTTPS, which you can accomplish directly from within the page. If you redirect, the page is first posted in plaintext, then in HTTPS. You certainly don't want that to happen, it defeats the whole point of the exercise. Same applies to your login and change-password pages, and any others where you transmit a password or other sensitive data. Redirection after the event is not secure.

Comment: Thanks for your awnser, so how could I do that ?

Comment: Just put a compete URL starting with https: into the action parameter of the form.

Comment: You'd also want [the page where you fill in the form itself to be served over HTTPS](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/1692/2435).

Comment: I got it, but the thing is that I would like the member to see it's secured with the https.

Comment: @user1388111: that's why you'd want the initial page to be using HTTPS too.

Comment: Thanks for the awnser Bruno, how could I do that ? Since I am French and don't really understand when there is too much text to read ;)